# PHP format date from returned data

Tags: php, mysql, time, format

I have a query that is returning a grid.  One of the columns brings back a column with a date, like this:

```
 echo "<td>{$Row[ETA]}</td>";
```

This displays the ETA from the database like this:

```
 2013-10-30 20:00:0
```

I basically want to remove the TIME portion and just keep the date.  Can this be done in the TD or do I have to the conversion elsewhere?  I would like to just do the conversion within the cell, if possible.

Let me know how this can be done.

Comment: Ideally you would do it in your query: `TIME(datecolumnname)`

Comment: Ideally you should listen to the suggestion by @JohnConde because it will limit your overhead between the database and your script but you can also `substr()` on the fly if you wish with `echo "<td>".substr($Row[ETA], 0, 10)."</td>";`

Comment: You mean [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - the substr version worked for me. Thanks. I gave you an up vote.

Comment: Accepted it. I think you helped me with another issue prior to this one. Thanks again.

Comment: Ha no problem, I am now curious as to what issue I helped with in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should listen to the suggestion by JohnConde because it will limit your overhead between the database and your script but you can also substr() on the fly if you wish like this:

```
echo "<td>".substr($Row['ETA'], 0, 10)."</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strtotime()` and `date()` functions to achieve this!!!

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Row[ETA]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well! if you want to get just date then you should use this function in your query

```
 DATE(date_field)
```

as this will return only date from the datetime column

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo it differently:

```
$eta = $Row['ETA'];
$etaDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($eta));
//now use $etaDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date](http://www.php.net/date) function to format the time, as what you're getting is a date as a string, you can use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime).

I think the format you're looking for is: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Row["ETA"]));`, you can either parse that into a variable and save it there, or you can concatenate the results together for the final string.